# Illegal assignment from List<or_guestsJSON> to or_guestsJSON

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, list, sobject

I an trying to write a testclass for a JSON object but het the error:

Illegal assignment from List to or_guestsJSON. How do I annotate the list in my testclass?

Class

```
    public class or_guestsJSON {
    public String lastLogin;
    public String lastName;
    public String zipCode;
    public String linkedinURL;
    public String city;
    public static List<or_guestsJSON> parse(String json) {
        return (List<or_guestsJSON>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<or_guestsJSON>.class);
    }
}
```

Test

```
@isTest
public class or_guestsJSONTest  {

 static testMethod void guestsTest() {
        String json=        '[{'+
        '    "lastLogin": "2018-05-20 10:33:41.0",'+
        '    "lastName": "GuestLast",'+
        '    "zipCode": "00000",'+
        '    "linkedinURL": "www.linkedin.com/guestprofile",'+
        '    "city": "California",'+
        '}]';
        or_guestsJSON obj = or_guestsJSON.parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`or_guestsJSON obj = or_guestsJSON.parse(json);` is your problem. The return value is a list, so you must create a list to hold the results:

```
or_guestsJSON[] obj = or_guestsJSON.parse(json);
```

... or ...

```
List<or_guestsJSON> obj = or_guestsJSON.parse(json);
```

Whichever you feel more comfortable using.